# How to fireEvent.scroll on a element inside container with react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to simulate the scrolling in a element contained in  a div, which is the one passed to `render` function.

I'm trying with something like this, but it seems that the div is not scrolling as my next `expect` is falling.

```
const content = (
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <LazyList itemRenderer={itemRenderer} items={items} minItemHeight={MIN_ITEM_HEIGHT} />
      </div>
    );
mockOffsetSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

const {debug, container, queryByText} = render(content);
const scrollContainer = container.querySelector('.ReactVirtualized__Grid');
debug(scrollContainer);
fireEvent.scroll(scrollContainer, {y: 100});
debug(scrollContainer);
```

Is this the correct way of firing the scroll event? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Any luck scrolling the element?

Comment: I have left this part unfinished until I have time or someone proposes a solution...

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried adding EventListener to your scroll container? I'm just not sure with that library you may have just used, but I'm pretty sure, in normal situations, calling scroll fireEvent without listener won't execute anything. Before your `fireEvent`, insert something like this:

```
scrollContainer.addEventListener('scroll', () => { /* some callback */ });
```

and change your fireEvent to:

```
fireEvent.scroll(scrollContainer, { target: { scrollY: 100 } });
```

Comment: @Eylen is the listener added to the container itself or is it a `window` listener? If so, you can `fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 100 } })` or `fireEvent.scroll(global, { target: { scrollY: 100 } })`

Comment: `scrollY` and `scrollX` only exists on the `window` object, I used `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to make it work with an html element.

Comment: Thanks @colinD! I didn't know that for html elements I had to use scrollLeft.

Answer (score 0):

[`scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) describes the scroll position of the entire document. Use [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) for individual containers.

```js
const scrollContainer = /* query */;
fireEvent.scroll(scrollContainer, { target: { scrollLeft: 500 } });
```